# Seemingly random "lost" requests on wifi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, packet-loss

I've recently started using new router (zyxel nr5101) and have some weird issues.
Most of the time the connection both on wifi and ethernet is perfect.
But It seems like sometimes (mostly on mobile devices - the ones using wifi) the requests take super long time (seconds) to process. It seems like the first "request" of my "session" is just lost somehow (packet loss?), and the next ones go through and back just fine.

Examples:

- Open Instagram and the photos are not loaded for a long time ()
- Open Instagram and click story, first story seems to be losing but if I skip it, the next ones are already loaded and working.
- Open Twitter and try to load new tweets - have to wait for a longer while.
- On youtube, the first video preview (on hover) does not load, but when I hover on any other video a preview is shown almost instantly.

On the same devices, the problem is not occurring when I use a mobile network.

I already tried, restarting the router and switching some settings, changing DNS servers, and simple pings to check for packet loss.
On the hardware side it's setup like this:

Mobile -(Wifi)-> Zyxel router -(Ethernet)-> Internet provider's router in bridge mode

Any ideas on what may be causing it or what tools to use to debug it?

Comment: Would you mind including your findings of the pings? You need to find out where exactly the problem happens: wifi connection, between the router and modem, DNS